# SeamPhaseListener - Could not start transaction - Seam 2.3, JSF 2 Tomcat 7, WAR

Tags: jsf, tomcat, transactions, migration, seam

[EDIT]
**The working project can be found at:

https://github.com/joergi77/JSF2_Richfaces4_Seam_23**
[/EDIT]

I migrated our old project to a newer setup.

Old setup

- Seam 2.2.2.Final
- JSF 1.2
- Richfaces 3.3.3.Final
- JBoss 5.1 GA
- EAR
- EJB
- Java EE5

---

New setup:

- Seam 2.3.1.Final
- JSF 2.1.2
- Richfaces 3.3.3.Final (should be compatible to JSF 2)
- Tomcat 7.0.57
- WAR
- NO EJB
- Java 7

The WAR file was already deployable and working with SEAM 2.2 and JSF 1.2. on the Tomcat 7.0.57

After that I was upgrading to SEAM 2.3 and JSF 2.
At the end was able to compile the WAR again and to deploy it on the Tomcat without any error logs.
But when I tried to enter the website via http://localhost:8080/ourproject I got this following error:

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not start transaction
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.begin(SeamPhaseListener.java:602)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.begin(SeamPhaseListener.java:587)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.handleTransactionsBeforePhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:326)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforeServletPhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:143)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.beforePhase(SeamPhaseListener.java:117)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.handleBeforePhase(Phase.java:228)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.Phase.doPhase(Phase.java:99)
    at com.sun.faces.lifecycle.LifecycleImpl.render(LifecycleImpl.java:139)
    at javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet.service(FacesServlet.java:594)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:303)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseXMLFilter.doXmlFilter(BaseXMLFilter.java:206)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.handleRequest(BaseFilter.java:290)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.processUploadsAndHandleRequest(BaseFilter.java:388)
    at org.ajax4jsf.webapp.BaseFilter.doFilter(BaseFilter.java:515)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:52)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:83)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.LoggingFilter.doFilter(LoggingFilter.java:60)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.IdentityFilter.doFilter(IdentityFilter.java:40)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.MultipartFilter.doFilter(MultipartFilter.java:90)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.ExceptionFilter.doFilter(ExceptionFilter.java:64)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.web.RedirectFilter.doFilter(RedirectFilter.java:45)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:69)
    at org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter.doFilter(SeamFilter.java:158)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:241)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:208)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:220)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:122)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:503)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:170)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:103)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:950)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:116)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:421)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1070)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:611)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:316)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745) 
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: no transaction
    at org.jboss.seam.transaction.NoTransaction.begin(NoTransaction.java:36)
    at org.jboss.seam.jsf.SeamPhaseListener.begin(SeamPhaseListener.java:597)
    ... 48 more
```

Here is our setup:

web.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<web-app version="3.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_3_0.xsd">

    <!-- Increase buffers so the entire response is sent at once (some people 
        say this could increase the performance). -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.responseBufferSize</param-name>
        <param-value>100000</param-value>
    </context-param>


    <context-param>  
         <param-name>javax.faces.DISABLE_FACELET_JSF_VIEWHANDLER</param-name>  
         <param-value>true</param-value>  
    </context-param>  


    <!-- Allows the browser to cache jsf's javascript -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>com.sun.faces.sendPoweredByHeader</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.BUFFER_SIZE</param-name>
        <param-value>100000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ##################### Facelets ##################### Disables facelets 
        debug page Defined in root pom - initial value: fale -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.DEVELOPMENT</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

        <!-- Stops facelets from scanning the xhtml's for changes Defined in root 
        pom - initial value: -1, for development 2 is recomanded -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.REFRESH_PERIOD</param-name>
        <param-value>-1</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
        <param-value>false</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- #####################  TagLib ##################### -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>facelets.LIBRARIES</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/taglibs/ourcompany-common.taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/taglibs/ourcompany-core.taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/taglibs/ourcompany-product.taglib.xml;
            /WEB-INF/taglibs/ourcompany-customer.taglib.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ##################### JSF ##################### -->
<!--    <context-param> -->
<!--        <param-name>javax.faces.DEFAULT_SUFFIX</param-name> -->
<!--        <param-value>.xhtml</param-value> -->
<!--    </context-param> -->

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.DEFAULT_EXPIRE</param-name>
        <param-value>1000000</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ##################### Ajax4Jsf ##################### -->
<!--    <context-param> -->
<!--        <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name> -->
<!--        <param-value>javax.faces.application.ViewHandlerWrappe</param-value> -->
<!--    </context-param> -->

<!--  Änderung JSF 2     -->
    <context-param>
       <param-name>org.ajax4jsf.VIEW_HANDLERS</param-name>
       <param-value>com.sun.facelets.FaceletViewHandler</param-value>
  </context-param>



    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadScriptStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.LoadStyleStrategy</param-name>
        <param-value>ALL</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <!-- ##################### Richfaces ##################### -->
    <context-param>
        <param-name>org.richfaces.SKIN</param-name>
        <param-value>ruby</param-value>
    </context-param>

    <filter>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamFilter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter>
        <display-name>RichFaces Filter</display-name>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <filter-class>org.ajax4jsf.Filter</filter-class>
    </filter>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>Seam Filter</filter-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </filter-mapping>

    <filter-mapping>
        <filter-name>richfaces</filter-name>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <dispatcher>REQUEST</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>FORWARD</dispatcher>
        <dispatcher>INCLUDE</dispatcher>
    </filter-mapping>

    <!-- ##################### Seam ##################### -->
    <listener>
        <listener-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamListener</listener-class>
    </listener>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.jboss.seam.servlet.SeamResourceServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>

    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Seam Resource Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/seam/resource/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.htm</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.html</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>

    <!-- ##################### Global Stuff ##################### -->

    <session-config>

        <session-timeout>40</session-timeout>
    </session-config>

    <security-constraint>
        <display-name>Restrict raw XHTML Documents</display-name>
        <web-resource-collection>
            <web-resource-name>XHTML</web-resource-name>
            <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
        </web-resource-collection>
        <auth-constraint />
    </security-constraint>

</web-app>
```

our pom.xml:

```
......
<parent>
    <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
    <artifactId>jboss-seam-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.3.1.Final</version>
</parent>
.....

<dependencies>


    <!-- Seam and JBOSS -->

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-ui</artifactId>
    </dependency> 

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.seam</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-seam-remoting</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-validator</artifactId>
        <version>3.1.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
        <version>3.3.1.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-annotations</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
        <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.GA</version> 
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-entitymanager</artifactId>
        <version>3.4.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.mail</groupId>
        <artifactId>mail</artifactId>
        <version>1.4</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.jboss.spec.javax.interceptor</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-interceptors-api_1.1_spec</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.0.Final</version>
    </dependency>


    <!-- View -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>




    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet.jsp</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.1</version>
        <scope>provided</scope>

    </dependency>


    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
      <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
      <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
      <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
      <version>${jsf.version}</version>
    </dependency>       

    <dependency>
        <groupId>jstl</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.2</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.facelets</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-facelets</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.15.B1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <artifactId>richfaces-ui</artifactId>
        <groupId>org.richfaces.ui</groupId>
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>  
        <groupId>org.richfaces.framework</groupId>  
        <artifactId>richfaces-impl-jsf2</artifactId>  
        <version>3.3.3.Final</version>  
    </dependency>  

    <!-- Commons -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>jboss</groupId>
        <artifactId>jboss-common-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.4.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
        <version>2.3</version>
    </dependency>

    <!-- Logging -->
    <dependency>
        <groupId>log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j</artifactId>
        <version>1.2.14</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.8</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>commons-logging</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-logging</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>javassist</groupId>
        <artifactId>javassist</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.0.GA</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>mysql</groupId>
        <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.1.18</version>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>net.sourceforge.jexcelapi</groupId>
        <artifactId>jxl</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.10</version>
        <type>jar</type>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>joda-time</groupId>
        <artifactId>joda-time</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

our faces-config.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<faces-config version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
 xmlns:xi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude"
 xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-facesconfig_2_0.xsd">    
 <lifecycle>
  <phase-listener>com.ourproject.view.jsf.listener.NavigationPhaseListener</phase-listener>
 </lifecycle>
</faces-config>
```

our components.xml

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<components xmlns="http://jboss.com/products/seam/components"
            xmlns:core="http://jboss.com/products/seam/core"
            xmlns:persistence="http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence"
            xmlns:transaction="http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction"
            xmlns:security="http://jboss.com/products/seam/security"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:mail="http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail"
            xmlns:async="http://jboss.com/products/seam/async"
            xmlns:web="http://jboss.com/products/seam/web"
            xsi:schemaLocation=
                "http://jboss.com/products/seam/core http://jboss.com/products/seam/core-2.3.xsd 
                http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence http://jboss.com/products/seam/persistence-2.3.xsd 
                http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction http://jboss.com/products/seam/transaction-2.3.xsd 
                http://jboss.com/products/seam/security http://jboss.com/products/seam/security-2.3.xsd
                http://jboss.com/products/seam/components http://jboss.com/products/seam/components-2.3.xsd
                http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail http://jboss.com/products/seam/mail-2.3.xsd
                http://jboss.com/products/seam/async http://jboss.com/products/seam/async-2.3.xsd
                http://jboss.com/products/seam/web http://jboss.com/products/seam/web-2.3.xsd">

    <core:init debug="true"/>


    <core:manager concurrent-request-timeout="30000"
        conversation-id-parameter="cid" conversation-timeout="1200000"
        parent-conversation-id-parameter="pid" />

    <transaction:entity-transaction entity-manager="#{entityManager}"/>

    <persistence:entity-manager-factory name="companyDatabase"/>

    <persistence:managed-persistence-context name="entityManager"
                               auto-create="true" 
                    entity-manager-factory="#{companyDatabase}"/>

    <security:jpa-identity-store
        user-class="com.ourcompany.user.model.Account"
        role-class="com.ourcompany.user.model.AccountRole" />

    <security:permission-manager permission-store="#{jpaPermissionStore}"/>      

    <security:jpa-permission-store
        user-permission-class="com.ourcompany.user.model.AccountPermission"/>

    <web:multipart-filter create-temp-files="true"
        max-request-size="100000000" url-pattern="*.html" />

    <web:logging-filter disabled="true" />

    <web:cache-control-filter name="imageCacheControlFilter"
        regex-url-pattern=".*(\.gif|\.png|\.jpg|\.jpeg)" value="max-age=86400" />

    <web:cache-control-filter name="textCacheControlFilter"
        regex-url-pattern=".*(\.css|\.js)" value="max-age=1400" />


</components>
```

I will also change to a newer Richfaces Version and maybe even a newer JSF Version, but only if I get this setup (which should work, as far as I know) to a running version.

Comment: @BalusC - it all worked with SEAM 2.2 as a WAR deployment on a Tomcat. Just with the switch to SEAM 2.3 it stopped working with this error mentioned above.

Comment: @BalusC - I explained the settings a little bit more!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The namespace used in component.xml in seam 2.3 has changed. You are still using the old one.

change `http://jboss.com/products/seam` to: `http://jboss.org/schema/seam`

If you have still problems check out the Migration from 2.2 to 2.3 in the JBoss Seam Documentation Chapter 4: http://docs.jboss.org/seam/2.3.1.Final/reference/pdf/seam-reference-guide.pdf

Comment: Definitely something I forgot.. now, I got some other errors, Iwill check it out and accept the answer, if this was the error. thanks @tak3shi

Answer (score 2):

There's an automated pluggable rule-based migration tool provided by JBoss, [Windup](http://windup.jboss.org). Run the tool and get a report of what needs to be done to migrate. This specific case is covered by the existing rules.

You can also customize this tool to cover your specific code patterns you need to migrate. Sharing your custom rules back to the community is highly appreciated.

Have fun :)